# Where can I ask about my graph algorithm?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, graphs

I am a programmer, but not a researcher; my level is below PhD.

I thought about extending the idea of smart pointers (where shared pointers counts references, but not releases cycles) to be fully automated in my planning of a computer language, like garbage collectors and works with all possible graphs, set of graphs and all possible actions adding/deleting edge between elements.

This works in my some examples. I want to ask about the possibility of proofing algorithm correctness or find bad examples. I prefer to either give a link to my methods in C++ (the language is not important) or paste it on-site (but the methods are quite big). Which site will be suitable for it?

Comment: Can you include  your _actual_ question (a truncated version of it possibly)? That will help in getting you a recommendation.